# What is a disc image burner?

Tags: cd-image

People help me please, it's says that a disc image burner wasn't found. What is this?

Answer (score 2):

All our OS files will be in image format like ISO. Burning A data file is not equal to the burning an ISO. both are different.But you can burn any CD image will General install of Ubuntu which consists of Brasero.Instead of that as for the best ISO burner i vote for K3b.

you can get it installed by

```
sudo apt-get install k3b
```

Any software you can install but the procedure is common.All you need to do is simple Right-click at that ISO file then it will show in options with what software you'd like to burn the cd-image file.

hope that helps.

Comment: Oops! Should have put my (now deleted) answer here. So: <br/> I also like K3b, but you can also use Brasero, Xfburn and many others.